# Creating Parent Child Records

Tags: google-app-maker

Can someone give me a bit of advice on the following (common) scenario.

I have a list of "Incident" records with an edit button for each
The Edit button opens up an "Incident" edit form for that record
The edit form contains a tab control with four tabs, each of which has a table for child (related) records: actions, documents, quotes and invoices

Take the first relation "actions". The table datasource is Incident: Action (relation).
A Add Action button opens a page with a form with datasource inherited action and type insert

I remove the Incident Id dropdown because I want this to be populated automatically from the parent record.

I add a text box and give it a value: @pages.Edit_Incident.datasource.item.Id
The text box is populated with the correct value

The submit button with OnClick Create New Item writes the record but does not persist the parent id or Incident_fk

What am I missing? This must be a common scenario.
If I enforce referential integrity in the model it doesn't save.
How can I persist the parent Id value to the Incident_fk field? I need to bind the text box to the datasource even though the page's datasource is correct

Comment: `I remove the Incident Id dropdown because I want this to be populated automatically from the parent record.` May be you shouldn't remove it.

Comment: Maybe I should because I want the software to (allow me to) do what all reasonable software should do and that is automate the stuff. Why would I want a user to use a dropdown to select the parent id for a child record. Where's the sense in that ?

Comment: I should add that if I left the dropdown and it populated the value automatically I would just disable the dropdown and leave it at that. But it doesn't populate the dropbox with the value of the parent id.

Comment: Some screenshots will be helpful to understand your question clearly and improve the chances of getting a answer.

Comment: Your third paragraph, where you open a page with datasource inherited 'Action', you should set that page datasource to 'Incident' instead. Then drag a form onto that page, when you select the datasource for the form choose 'Incident: Action (relation)' and for the form type choose 'Insert Only'. That is how simple it is. Your form datasource after creation will be 'Incident: Action (relation) (create)', which is what you want. No dropdowns are needed to select the Incident relation, it is automatically built in.